# Add various numbers from one to another

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is there a way that you can use a for loop to add various numbers from one to another? Fill in the blanks ___ with one or more line.

```
<input id="minNumber">
<input id="maxNumber">
```

```
for(var i = 0; i < ___; i++) {
  var num = document.getElementById("minNumber");
  var num2 = document.getElementById("maxNumber");
    _________________________________________________
}
```

Similarly, it is like adding 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6... onwards, but allowing the user to set the smallest and largest values to add between. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Syntax of `for-loop` is ***the initialization, the condition, and the afterthought***

You should be using `initial value` as min and max value in condition.

```js
var num = +document.getElementById("minNumber").value;
var num2 = +document.getElementById("maxNumber").value;
var total = 0;

for (var i = num; i <= num2; i++) {
  total += i;
}
console.log(total);
```

```html
<input id="minNumber" type="number" value="1">
<input id="maxNumber" type="number" value="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
<input id="minNumber">
<input id="maxNumber">

var num = document.getElementById("minNumber");
var num2 = document.getElementById("maxNumber");

for(var i = num; i < num2; i++)
{

_________________________________________________

}
```

This will iterate from your minNumber to maxNumber which user has defined.